# Existe alguma maneira de debugar o PHP via console do navegador?

Tags: php, debug

Existe alguma maneira de debugar o PHP via console do navegador?

Eu as vezes quero debugar um valor, no sistema em produção, porém não gostaria que o usuário percebesse. Daí tive a ideia de usar o console do navegador.

É possível fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
console_log(['nome' => 'Wallace']);
```

E no console aparecer:

```
{nome: "wallace"}
```

Answer (score 8):

Eu mesmo fiz a pergunta e respondi, pois nunca vi alguém com essa curiosidade.

Existe sim uma maneira, e eu a criei nesse [gist](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/73886a39b3f391a71055)

O código é bem simples. É possível passar infinitos parâmetros para serem debugados com essa função.

Código-Fonte:

```
function console_log()
{
    foreach (func_get_args() as $mixed) {
        printf('<script>console.log(%s)</script>', json_encode($mixed));
    }
}
```

O uso disso seria assim:

```
console_log($_GET, $_POST, $_SERVER);
```

Daí, basta você abrir o console e ver o que acontece ;)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito boa ideia de postar aqui, já fiz isto várias vezes, mas sempre achei isto uma gambiarra master monster mas quebra um galho.

Comment: Bem interessante, mas achei que seria algo em relação a pausar o código. Isso não seria apenas exibição de dados?

Comment: Eu chamo de debugar também exibir o valor da variável (como no var_dump)

Comment: vocês não gostam do xdebug não?

Comment: Depende. As vezes ele enche o saco com o negócio de Maximum call 100, em recursividade

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que vi isso nesse post: http://www.paulund.co.uk/output-php-data-in-browser-console pra debugar um resultado em produção é bom, mas ainda sim qualquer um com acesso ao console poderia ver, testei alguns plugins pro chrome como https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/php-console/nfhmhhlpfleoednkpnnnkolmclajemef e não tiveram bons resultados...

Comment: @WallaceMaxters da uma olhada nesse aqui: http://www.codeforest.net/debugging-php-in-browsers-javascript-console parece bem mais completo.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues, prefiro usar `json_encode` em todos os valores. Dá para ver o `true`, `false` e `null`. O PHP vai imprimir um vazio se seguir o exemplo do link

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma diferente onde não seria possível inserir no console (caso de algum erro ocorrece após a chamada da função que você criou) mas debugando externamente seria escrever o resultado da variável em um arquivo externo desta forma:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($featuresArray);
$result = ob_get_clean();
$file = 'C:\PRINT_VAR_DUMP.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $result);
```

O conteúdo salvo neste arquivo pode ser aberto no notepad++ (exibe identado).